# Conversations in XMPP

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm implementing an XMPP Chat and **I was wondering if there is any XEP regarding lists of conversations (like WhatsApp)**. With message archiving, the clients can retrieve the message history with a given user, but if they open the application for the first time, they doesn't know which users they've previously talked to.
I use ejabberd as my server.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not know of such a XEP. Most XMPP systems assume you will have a roster. Then, it's easy to fetch chat history between you and a particular user just by querying the Message Archive (XEP-0313) with that user's JID.

That being said, I also believe a roster-agnostic Chat-partners XEP would be nice to have.